# Highcharts and Excel Slicers

Tags: jquery, excel, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to integrate something like excel slicers into highcharts. For those that are not familiar with slicers, here's a nice pic illustrating it. You can almost thing of it as checkboxes/radio buttons that alters the criteria of the query

Is there a neat way for this to happen by any chance? How could I refresh the JSON behind the graph dynamically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you will need to programmatically tie each slicer to the chart.

In other words, when one of the slicers changes, you will need to handle it via a JavaScript event, slice the data (either locally or via an AJAX call to your backend), and then redraw the chart using the updated data.

Comment: Any examples similar to this? I work best with examples so this would be perfect, otherwise I might just have to start from scratch :-(

Comment: Take look at the article about dynamically preprocessing http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing . Exampel of using ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/ScPmM/

Comment: I'd probably go down the jQuery UI buttonset approach and have multiple sets.